# Java - Inject Resources in Super Class without exposing Setters in Base Class

Tags: java

Perhaps this is a simple question but I still have not come with a solution for it. I have this configuration of classes:

```
abstract class SuperA {
   Resource a;
   Resource b;

   public SuperA() {
   }

   public SuperA(Resource a, Resource b) {
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
   }

   protected Resource getResourceA() {
       return a;
   }

   protected Resource getResourceB() {
       return b;
   }

}

class BaseA extends SuperA {
   public method1() {
       Resource myResource = getResourceA();
   }
}

class Manager {
   public Manager() {
      // I want to instantiate BaseA and inject some resources, but can't do
      // it through the constructor
      BaseA baseA = new BaseA(/*can't place parameters*/);
      // I could use Setters, but this would expose the Setters to BaseA too...
      baseA.setResourceA(new Resource());
      baseA.setResourceB(new Resource());
   }
}
```

In this case I would like to inject the Resources into the Super class without exposing any Setter to its Base class and without inheriting the constructor, is there any way to do this?

**UPDATE - CLARIFICATION**

The `BaseA` class is the extension of an API and I don't want other users to have access to modify the resources injected by the core engine which instantiates `BaseA`. I want `BaseA` to *USE* the resources *NOT* to modify them.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the constructor?

Comment: I can use the constructor but would need to inherit it from the Base class and I would like to keep the base class without access to alter the resources.

Comment: What do you mean by _need to inherit it_? If `BaseA` extends `SuperA`, it has access to all visible `SuperA` constructors.

Comment: Also, if the resources are private, and any setters are private, BaseA can't alter the resources once an object of BaseA has been constructed. They have to be passed in to the constructor, but the constructed object can't alter them.

Comment: No, it does not. the `Manager` class tries to get an instance in `BaseA` but it cannot see the constructors of `SuperA` unless `BaseA` overrides it. That is the problem. And why the downvote???

Comment: Just define an appropriate constructor in `BaseA` that calls the appropriate super constructor. A constructor is not something that is _inherited_.

Comment: If you don't want to do it through constructor or setter which actually is right approach, the only way i can think of is through reflection

Comment: That is exactly what I don't want to do. Yes, I know it is not inherited I just didn't find the word. But I would like to keep `BaseA` without access to alter the Resources.

Comment: If you don't want it to alter resources, then why are you asking for a way to set resources? Your question is very unclear right now.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I posted some clarification update.

Comment: You said it yourself in your edit: you want to *use*. Inheritance usually allows a great deal of stuff with side effects. So don't inherit: encapsulate instead! Are you really sure you want to use inheritance? If you have constraints like that, you usually don't.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Yes, I've been thinking the same. Seems like I'll need to use a wrapper to inject the resources and this wrapper can be set to `BaseA` without exposing any setter or constructor. No inheritance.

Comment: If you want `Manager` to decide those resources, you have no other options.

Comment: Yes, `Manager` decides what resources are injected into the new instance of `BaseA`.

Comment: Then just declare a constructor that accepts those resources. I don't see the problem.

Comment: I'm a little lost, wouldn't just 'package visible' be what he wants? I missed all the extra comments here while writing up my answer, but I don't see why this is that complicated. He wants SuperA to have methods that 'manager' can use to modify values, but not inherited classes? correct? (As long as 'manager' is in the same package doesn't this just become my answer? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be a setter like this, where it is 'package visible' and 'final'

> You use the final keyword in a method declaration to indicate that the
>   method cannot be overridden by subclasses. from [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html)

then you use ' package-private' access-level modifier (not exact quote to follow... but explanation)

> (no 'public', 'private', or 'protected' stated) This means that the
>   class itself can see/use the method, Classes in the same exact package
>   can see/use the method, but sub-classes and world can NOT see/use the
>   method  [From javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

'package-private' alone might solve your issue, but I would put 'final' just to make it more-obvious the behavior desired, so as to help with future work on the code, etc.

for example:

```
abstract class SuperA {
   // making these private also helps
   // because it limits child classes to ONLY use getters
   // they can't even 'fiddle with' the raw values
   private Resource a;
   private Resource b;

   // would you want this public? perhaps also no 'access-modifier' 
   // the 'exact' specifics of a lot of this class would depend on your
   // specific use case (But I'd think you would want this package-only too most likely)
   public SuperA() {
   }

   // note no 'access-modifier', means package use only.
   SuperA(Resource a, Resource b) {
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
   }


   // can also have the same with setters
   // again no 'access-modifier' 
   final setResourceA(Resource a){ this.a = a;}
   final setResourceB(Resource b){ this.b = b;}

   public final Resource getResourceA() {
       return a;
   }


   public final Resource getResourceB() {
       return b;
   }

}
```

This would allow your library to access these method(s) but not allow subclasses or 'world'

Comment: Yes, it works to allow only the core api to have access to the setters and no sub-classes nor anybody else. Thank you.

Comment: And what if the `Manager` class is in different package but in the same jar file? I had to move the `Manager` class to the same package of `SuperA` in order to make it work.

Comment: Then you refactor your library if you can. Because this is the right way to give the functionality he wants. Using reflection or something else so as to not move a class(es) seems a little short sighted to me. Sure there might be a valid edge case somewhere for that(Especially in legacy code or code that is already making heavy use of package-visibility, and you'd need a whole refactor), but I would still argue that this approach is the best for 'general cases'

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear what the motivation is for not allowing access to the base class of a constructor, when that's clearly (IMHO) the obvious best choice:

```
class BaseA extends SuperA {  
    public BaseA() {
        super(new Resource(), new Resource()); // whatever
    }
}
```

or there's reflection:

```
class Manager {
    public Manager() throws Exception {
        BaseA baseA = new BaseA();
        Field f = SuperA.class.getDeclaredField("a");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(baseA, new Resource()); // however you create a Resource
        // similar for field "b"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, reflection would be a solution. Event though it comes with a performance penalty if it is a high-traffic routine.

Comment: @Joe see edits to answer for some code to do it. The performance penalty is not that high - if it's the solution you need, just use it.

Comment: Yes, I'll consider it. I'll need to verify what would be the cost of reflection in this part of the code. In a not so transited code that would not be a problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Joe I just did a quick performance test of the above reflection-base code: less than 10 microseconds (0.01 milliseconds) for the above code. Unless you're creating thousands of these things per second, performance shouldn't be a problem.